# Reading specific lines with unknown placement in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, streamreader

I am trying to code a program to read out user-groups from a .txt-file and to put said groups into a listbox. An example for a group list would be the following:

*User*

*-------------*

*Group1*

*Group2*

*Group3*

*[space]*

*[space]*

*next user*

Every user has is in an unknown amount of groups, thats why there are two spaces, just to seperate everything.

Here is my progress so far:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        //users.txt contains all users
        //in the same directory there are multiple lists with given groups
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("c:\\ADHistory\\users.txt", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
        string line = string.Empty;
        try {
            //Read the first line of text
            line = sr.ReadLine();
            //Continue to read until you reach end of file
            while (line != null) {
                listboxNames.Items.Add(line);
                //Read the next line
                line = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            //close the file
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(f.Message.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            //close the file
            sr.Close();
        }
    }

    private void listboxNames_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        //as soon as you choose a user from the first list
        //you may choose a date to look at all groups the user is in.
        listboxDates.Items.Clear();
        DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\ADHistory");
        FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");

        //this adds all dates into the second listbox
        //and removes users.txt from the list.
        foreach (FileInfo file in Files) {
            listboxDates.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
        for (int n = listboxDates.Items.Count - 1; n >= 0; --n)
        {
            string removelistitem = "users";
            if (listboxDates.Items[n].ToString().Contains(removelistitem))
            {
                listboxDates.Items.RemoveAt(n);
            }
            //this displays the user below the listboxes,
            //because of styling purposes
            string user = Convert.ToString(this.listboxNames.SelectedItem);
            labelName.Content = user;

        }
    }

    //here we have my main problem.
    //I can't find a solution to add the groups to the last listbox
    private void listboxDates_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string user = Convert.ToString(labelName.Content);
        listboxGroups.Items.Clear();
        string path = "C:\\ADHistory\\";
        path += Convert.ToString(this.listboxDates.SelectedItem);

        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(path))
        {
            if (line.Contains(user))
            {
                while (line != " ")
                {
                    listboxGroups.Items.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I really hope you can help me.

**EDIT**

This question has been answered, so there is no need for mor answers.
Thanks for all the comments :)

Comment: What your code is unable to accomplish??

Comment: You presented what you have done but not what's your problem you need help with

Comment: Your question says you are reading a single file but your code reads multiple files... What are really having a problem with.

Comment: It should take all groups a specific user is in and put them in a third listbox. But it doesn't. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: ...have you looked into passing the result from the .txt file into a string list and using the .Split() method....?...

Comment: @Dbuggy the second listbox lets you choose the file you want to read from. then, in the chosen file, it should search for the user and display the groups in the third listbox

Comment: @Nils Fahle And where does your code fails. Have you tried stepping through your code ?

Comment: @Dbuggy I don't get any errors. All it does is leaving me with an empty listbox. I've stepped through it multiple times, but I couldn't find a solution. That's the reason my question is here.

Comment: Use for loop instead of for each. Have your while loop when you find the line for user as the same, and increase the loop variable with ++ inside the while loop and read the next line. Don't forget to check for the string array length before setting line = fileLines[lineIndex]

Comment: You should first assign the list of files to string[] fileLines before the for loop of course

Comment: @OguzOzgul as I'm relatively new to coding, would you mind correcting my code and post it as an answer?

Comment: Your problem is, when the line for the user is found, you test if line == " " without proceeding to the next and your while loop should exit immediately then.

Comment: Yup. If you can wait for 5 mins

Comment: I agree with @Oguz. It seems to me that the `while (line != " ")
` loop should just be omitted. At best, it should be an `if` instead of ` while` (since the loop can't _change_ `line`). And assuming you've validated the user name entry and are sure it's not a space, then you don't need another check for `!= " "` after the `Contains()` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, when the line for the user is found, you test if line == " " without proceeding to the next and your while loop should exit immediately then

Use for loop instead of for each. Have your while loop when you find the line for user as the same, and increase the loop variable with ++ inside the while loop and read the next line. Don't forget to check for the string array length before setting line = fileLines[lineIndex]

Therefore, here is the code that should work for you

```
string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

for (int lineIndex = 0; lineIndex < fileLines.Length; lineIndex++)
{
    string line = fileLines[lineIndex];
    if (line.Contains(user))
    {
        while(++lineIndex < fileLines.Length && (line = fileLines[lineIndex]) != " ")
        {
            listboxGroups.Items.Add(line);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

However, if the file is huge, you might want not to read all it's lines into memory, here is another approach which works with File.ReadLines()

```
IEnumerator<string> fileLines = File.ReadLines(path).GetEnumerator();

while (fileLines.MoveNext())
{
    string line = fileLines.Current;
    if (line.Contains(user))
    {
        while (fileLines.MoveNext())
        {
            line = fileLines.Current;
            if (line == " ")
            {
                break;
            }
            listboxGroups.Items.Add(line);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @nils I've made a mistake with the break, please use the version after the edit

Comment: The File.ReadLines gives me following error:
Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Sorry. That's right. I tried with ReadAllLines, will fix it now

Comment: @nils But using File.ReadAllLines() will read all the lines in the file into memory. That's why I meant to fix the code. I am adding the code that works with ReadLines anyway into my answer. You can choose either.